# How to find whether three coordinate​s are collinear

Tags: java

I am sure that my questions is a very generic one , probably a pure java problem. However i have been trying to find a way to identify whether three coordinates are collinear using the same logic of finding it doesnt seem to work on examples which take 'Points' as inputs. 
Two approaches can be
1. Find the area of the triangle forming the three coordinates/points . If they are on the same line; the value of area must be zero.
2. Split the line joining these coordinates into two and find the individual slopes for the same. If they are on the same line, the slopes will be same.

The following is the method i am trying.

```
private
boolean collinearCheck( Coordinate endPointOne , Coordinate intersection,Coordinate  endPointTwo ){ 
boolean isCollenear = false; 

//Area of triangle approach
double area = (Math.round(endPointOne.x )* (Math.round(intersection.y) - Math.round  (endPointTwo.y)) + Math.round(intersection.x )* (Math.round(endPointTwo.y) - Math.round (endPointOne.y)) + 
Math.round(endPointTwo.x) * (Math.round(endPointOne.y) - Math.round(intersection.y)));
if((endPointOne.x * (intersection.y - endPointTwo.y) + intersection.x *  (endPointTwo.y - endPointOne.y) + 
endPointTwo.x * (endPointOne.y - intersection.y))<= 0) if(Math.round(area) <= 0)
{
isCollenear = true;
} 

 // Slope Approach
  double numeratorOne = Math.round(intersection.y) - Math.round(endPointOne.y);
  double denominatorOne = Math.round(intersection.x) - Math.round(endPointOne.x);
  double numeratorTwo = Math.round(endPointTwo.y) - Math.round(intersection.y);
  double denominatorTwo = Math.round(endPointTwo.x) - Math.round(intersection.x);
  double result1 = Math.round(numeratorOne/denominatorOne);
  double result2 = Math.round(numeratorTwo/denominatorTwo);
  if(result1== 0 && result2==0){
   isCollenear = true;
  }
 return isCollenear; 
  }
```

In both these cases while using coordinates as inputs ; even for simingly collinear situations i end up getting values like 4 etc for the area. And for situations that are clearly non collinear; i end up getting the same value for slope.

Is there a way I can obtain the clear notifier of collinearity using any construct? Is my approach correct?
The sample value for coordinates i pass to the method are Coordinate endPointOne  = -26.666666666666686, 32.38095238095238  .... etc

Looking forward for your inputs.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not checking the area code, but to check if three points are colinear. Then the formula is:

points (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3).

It is supposed to be colinear iff,

```
 (y2-y1)      (y3-y2)
 -------  =   -------
 (x2-x1)      (x3-x2)
```

So the code should be,

```
  if(result1==result2){
      isCollenear = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things: do you know that `Math.round` does `(long)Math.floor(a + 0.5d)` and comparing doubles by `==` is really not good idea go for something like `Math.abs(a - b) < EPSILON` compare the difference to some decimal place.

Comment: +1 for the comparision method, simple, precise and not CPU eating.

Answer (score 0):

`Split the line joining these coordinates into two and find the individual slopes for the same. If they are on the same line, the slopes will be same.`
 -- this approach is the best to find whether three points are  collinear or not, But your code need little modification,

Modify these Lines

```
double result1 = Math.round(numeratorOne/denominatorOne);
double result2 = Math.round(numeratorTwo/denominatorTwo);
if(result1== 0 && result2==0){
isCollenear = true;
}
```

To

```
double result1 = numeratorOne/denominatorOne;
double result2 = numeratorTwo/denominatorTwo;
double r3= Math.round((result1 -result2)*1000.0); // to apply 0.001 tolerance 

if(r3==0)
{
   isCollenear = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way.

1. The formula for the line between those two points (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) and (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>) is:

   y = y<sub>1</sub> + ((y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>) / (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)) * (x - x<sub>1</sub>)
2. Test if (x<sub>3</sub>, y<sub>3</sub>) satisfies the above formula ... within an acceptable delta (to allow for rounding error).

For the most accurate results, select the points such that (x<sub>3</sub>, y<sub>3</sub>) is the middle point on the line; e.g. x<sub>3</sub> is between x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub>

(Beware of the degenerate case where (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>) is zero ...)